# Newly created git branches in Azure DevOps not showing up in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

I had cloned a git project hosted in Azure DevOps using Visual Studio 2017. Then a branch was created in the Azure Devops portal. Now I do not see newly created branch in Visual Studio. What do I need to do in Visual Studio 2017 to sync the newly crated branch to show up in VS 2017?

Comment: you should do a fetch

Answer (score 7):

The [Azure devops documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/pulling?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio) suggests a sync:

[image: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/_img/pulling/synchronization-menu.png?view=azure-devops]

> Visual Studio uses the Sync view in Team Explorer to fetch changes. Changes downloaded by fetch are not applied until you Pull or Sync the changes.

Note that showing all branches history is *still* (Q2 2019) [a pending feature request...](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/382989/show-combined-git-branch-history-including-common.html)

Comment: vs2019 after sync, you move to Synchronization on your current branch. I needed to press fetch, to see the new  branch in remotes/origin branches.

Comment: @AJAJ That makes sense indeed: only a fetch would update the remotes namespace with the remote branches.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your local git repository is connected to Azure DevOps.
2. Click Sync --> Click Pull to get all changes from remote git repository.
3. Back to Home and click Branches, you will see local branches and remote branches at here. Double click your remote branch, then you can have the local branch and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch was enough for me, then I could see the remote branch.